# Updating states using optimistic locking and transactions in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Suppose I have two tables like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS assets (
  id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  created timestamp DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  customer uuid NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS asset_attributes (
  id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  created timestamp DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  asset uuid NOT NULL,
  attributes jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

I have `assets` that are owned by customers; `assets` can have `attributes` that may change over time. I need to be able to refer to old versions of `attributes` so rather than `UPDATE` a column in the `assets` table, I instead `INSERT` a new row in the `asset_attributes` table. This is sometimes called "non-destructive updates".

```sql
INSERT INTO asset_attributes 
  (
    asset,
    attributes
  ) 
VALUES 
  (
    '92675e0c-7473-435f-b48e-8de1feb2164b',
    '{ "foo": "bar" }'::jsonb
  ) 
RETURNING id
```

I can get the latest `asset_attributes` value for a given `asset` using `GROUP BY`, total ordering, etc.

My server works by fetching the latest `asset_attributes` for a given `asset`, doing some processing on it, and then pushing a new row.

Now, the problem with this is that if two processes try to do this at the same time, then a new value might get pushed before the second process has finished, and so it will be working on a stale value.

What I would like to happen is for an update on a stale value to fail so that the process knows to start again from the latest value.

Pseudo-code:

```ml
process_attributes(asset_id): 
  let latest_attributes = fetch_latest_attributes(asset_id)

  let next_attributes = do_work(latest_attributes)

  let did_update_succeed = update_attributes_from_previous(asset_id, latest_attributes, next_attributes)

  if not did_update_succeed
  then
    // Try again from the beginning
    process_attributes(asset_id)
```

I am not sure what the best way to write the SQL for `update_attributes_from_previous` is.

**How can I achieve this with Postgres?**

---

My attempt at a solution:

```sql
INSERT INTO asset_attributes (asset, attributes)
SELECT
  '92675e0c-7473-435f-b48e-8de1feb2164b' AS asset,
  '{ "foo": "bar" }'::jsonb AS attributes
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT id
      FROM asset_attributes
      WHERE asset = '92675e0c-7473-435f-b48e-8de1feb2164b'
    )
  OR 
  EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT id
      FROM
        (
          SELECT id
          FROM asset_attributes
          WHERE asset = '92675e0c-7473-435f-b48e-8de1feb2164b'
          ORDER BY created DESC, id
          LIMIT 1
        ) AS latest
      WHERE 
        id = 'fc114de7-93a2-44dc-be5c-92999caa0eb0' -- ID of latest asset_attributes at start of processing
    )
RETURNING id, created, asset, attributes ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would kill two birds with one stone by adding a `current_assets_attributes_id` to the `assets` table.

I would then use the `assets` row as a lock as follows:

```
select a.id, aa.attributes 
  from assets a
       join asset_attributes aa 
         on aa.id = a.current_assets_attributes_id
 where a.id = xxx
for update of assets;
```

Processing pseudocode:

1. Modify the retrieved `attributes`
2. Insert the new `asset_attributes` record `returning id`
3. `update assets set current_assets_attributes_id = yyy where id = xxx`
4. `commit` (or `rollback`), thereby releasing the lock

Other processes attempting to modify the same `asset` will block on the `select. . . for update`.

This would also work without adding the `current_assets_attributes_id` to the `assets` table so long as you use the `select. . . where id = xxx. . . for update of assets` since the lock does not care whether you actually perform an `update` and will prevent any other process from locking that row until the transaction owning the lock ends.

Comment: Isn't this a pessimistic locking model?

Comment: @sdgfsdh Yes, it is.  The fact that there are no `update` statements executed in your process makes optimistic locking very difficult.  You could explore LarsBr.'s answer, but I think you take on more complexity for little gain.  You can also forgo the `for update` by using `repeatable read` like Laurenz Albe suggested, but that requires that you perform an `update` within your transaction.  I would use explicit, pessimistic locking--especially if the updates are handled by a running process that you control instead of some user in the middle of a multi-page web flow.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way for that would be to include both the ID of the most recent entry as well as the condition for the most recent entry in the WHERE condition for the INSERT.
This could be done in a EXISTS( ) clause that evaluates to TRUE if and only if the ID is still the most recent entry.

For this scheme to work, there must be an immediate COMMIT after the INSERT.